# Is there any way to bookmark some questions in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I would like to recollect some questions. Some time after I find them, I have to refer them. When my first search used some keyword, which is not in my mind after some time. So I would like to keep those links in my profile and refer them later. Is there any way to bookmark such things in Stack Overflow itself, like Browser BookMarks?